# KA336 replacement parts

Tags: component-selection, voltage-reference, substitution

Can you replace a KA336 with a TL431 directly?

I have a circuit board with a broken KA336 and I can't find it here in my country, not even the LM336. It is a 2.5V shunt regulator.

[image: KA336 2.5 picture]

The adjust pin on the printed board is disconnected, so apparently it is working as a common zener.

Comment: Data sheets look similar - why not try it?

Comment: i will, i just wanted to know if someone had replaced one of those regulators with the TL431

Comment: LM336-2.5 seems to be readily available on ebay tough. From lots of countries beside china, so less likely to be fakes.

Comment: yes, but i live in Uruguay and i need those circuits working before January 3

Comment: *i live in Uruguay and i need those circuits working before January 3* We only deal with engineering related problems here, logistics are your own problem. You're lucky if someone suggests a component/product because normally that's not done here. If you are unable to get that component/product on time, what can we do about that? Nothing!

Comment: Do you know who much shunt current it should be drawing? The TL431 is a very popular IC used in switch-mode power supplies, so if you can find an old PSU to cannibalize...